# confusion for .equals() and == C#?

Tags: c#, equals-operator, referenceequals

so I have read in the article that `==` check if the object reference is same or not  `.equals()` check if data is the same or not but when I am writing some program on my own I am having confusion.

I have a class person I which I am passing 10,20 in my constructor 
now I have created another object p1 and p2

```
person p = new person(10,20);
person p1;
p1 = p;

person p2=new person(10,20);
Console.WriteLine(p==p1); //true
Console.WriteLine(p.Equals(p1)); //true
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(p,p1)); //true
Console.WriteLine(p == p2); //false
Console.WriteLine(p.Equals(p2)); //false confusion same data
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(p, p2));//false
```

> now I have confusion in p.equals(p2) both have the same data 10,20 so why
>   false

Comment: Because you didn't implement; `Equals()` override, `==`  override, nor implement the `IEquatable` interface, thus they are different objects so they cannot be equal.

Comment: `==` checks if two instances are the same reference (which is, more or less are they pointing at the same object in memory). `Equals` checks the content. But for `Equals` to work on a self defined type, you have to override it. Otherwise it falls back to `Object.Equals` which of course does not know about the properties of the custom type.

Comment: if that case then why  (p.Equals(p1)); is true ? @derpirscher

Comment: I don't know cthe exact implementation of `Object.Equals` but it may check for reference equality, which implies of course equality as well

Comment: @derpirscher You do not need to know the exact implementation, because that method Object.Equals is well documented. If it is an reference type then Equals is the same as ReferenceEquals

Answer (score 0):

`p.Equals(p1)` it will use Equals method of your object.

You did not implement it will compare address of two object, if it same address in memory it will true.

Note `p1 = p` that p1 and p refer to same address in memory.

`person p2=new person(10,20)` it will create object in difference address in memory with same content of `p` object

p.Equals(p2) has difference address in memory and no implement Equals method, it will return false.

You can implement Equals method like this

```
  public override bool Equals(Object obj)
       {
          person p= obj as person;
          if (p == null)
             return false;
          else
             return obj.p1 == p.p1 && obj.p2 = p.p2; // assum your property
       }
```

And you need implement GetHashCode method too like

```
public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return this.p1 + this.p2; //sample
  }
```

Comment: p.Equals(p1) is coming as true  but p.Equals(p2) is false without override method

Comment: @HienNguyen - If you `override bool Equals` you must also `override int GetHashCode()`.

Comment: thanks Enigmativity, i updated answer, please remove down vote :)

Comment: but stringbuilder is also refrence type and if i create 2 string builder with same data i/e test and say s1.equals(s2)-->true //as it check data @HienNguyen